# How can I bind an Integer to a Textfield using divide?

Tags: java, javafx

I am having a little trouble with bindings and properties. `info.durationIntegerProperty()` is a SimpleIntegerProperty which I would like to bind to a Textfield.

I know I can do

```
textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(info.durationIntegerProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());
```

But now I want to divide the "duration" by 1000 dynamically, something like

```
textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(info.durationIntegerProperty().divide(1000), new NumberStringConverter());
```

but I get the Error

> The method bindBidirectional(Property<?>, Format) in the type
> StringProperty is not applicable for the arguments (IntegerBinding,
> NumberStringConverter)

Why does divide change the Type from Property to Binding? Why can I not `bindBidirectional` with an IntegerBinding?
I know I could write my own StringConverter but I thought there might be a better solution..?

Comment: What is `info`?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: look at the type of `integerProperty.divide()`- it's probaly not a property, or is it?

Comment: No access to Javadocs right now, but doesn't `integerProperty().divide(...).asString()` work?

Comment: @James_D same here ;) hmm .. suspect that intProperty.divide returns a Binding, whereas bindBidirectional(something) needs something to be a Property. asString on the Binding wouldn't help because it'll also return a Binding. Or what do I overlook?

Comment: @kleopatra That is absolutely correct. I am not sure I understand the use of those mathematical functions on the property correctly. I thought I could use them to dynamically do calculations while binding. But the fact that divide(int) returns an IntegerBinding and divide(float) returns a FloatBinding throws me off... (asString returns a StringBinding)
How may I elegantly solve my problem then?